# stdClass object information PHP

Tags: php, stdclass

there's this stdClass thing in PHP:

```
<?php
$fakeobj->hi = "o";
echo $fakeobj->hi;
```

See?  Is this php4?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question in a manner that gives the impression you actually can make complete sentences?

Comment: I don't see a question here, other than wondering if it is PHP4. Is that all you want to know?

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StdClass is present in php 4 and 5. Its not necessarily either - its just a basic class implementation with no methods - a value object. Its used by some functions when they need to generate an object without an explicit user defined class for example `json_decode` or a value object returned by a SOAP request when a class isnt explicitly mapped. Of course a user/developer can also use it.